# Connection to SQL

Tags: vba, excel, connection, connection-string

I want to add a connection to a sheet so that each time a cell is refreshed, a value is passed in from SQL. I want it to reference a textbox on one of the other sheets for where ID =

How do I set the connection to refresh with that value. What do I put in my connection string? I can get it to work staticly.

Comment: VBA. If he hadn't set the tags before, he has now.

Answer (score 0):

Excel has a handy little feature called "Import External Data".  Here's what I would do:

1. In your Excel file, goto **Data**->**Import External Data**->**New Database Query** (In your case, the Import Data option won't be the best method)
2. Go through the wizard. Choose your datasource, etc. Except on the last option, choose **View data or edit query in Microsoft Query**
3. MS Query is basically a little query designer. Choose the **show/hide criteria** icon (looks like eyeglass + funnel).
4. This interface for putting in criteria is much like Access.  Choose a field and instead of hard coding values, use **[Criteria]** (or something).
5. Close out MS Query and go back to the Excel file.
6. In your new data range, right-click to **Parameters**.->**Get the value from the following cell**
7. Don't forget the **Refresh automatically when cell value changes**

To summarize, you are importing external data using a parameter, and declaring the value of that parameter to be a cell in your file.  Well, that was a nice little break from my own work.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What causes the cell to be refreshed? The connection string will be dependent on what database you are using. The below example uses Access and needs a reference to Microsoft ActiveX Dataobjects 2.8

The data is put in cell(1,1) on sheet1. The where clause is taken from textbox1 on sheet2:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 

Dim sqlQuery As String

sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE " & Worksheets("sheet2").TextBox1.Text
fetchData "C:\file_databases\myDatabase.accdb", Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1), sqlQuery

End Sub

Private Function fetchData(databaseName As String, targetRange As Range, sqlQuery As String)

Dim connection As New ADODB.connection
Dim records As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim connectionString As String
connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & databaseName & ";"

connection.Open connectionString
records.Open sqlQuery, connection
targetRange.CopyFromRecordset records

records.Close
connection.Close

End Function
```